# Rating system and changing the loop

Tags: loop, rating

Alright, so I want to see who can help me implement this idea I have.

I just want one single Icon next to a post. If you click it, then you "Heart" it or "Love it". The post has a counter to see how many people "heart" it. Then I want to change the loop to show off "Trending" posts, "Hot Posts" or something along those lines. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GD Star plugin implements this.  It is thumbs up and thumbs down in their parlance but  the image sets are configurable.

http://www.gdstarrating.com/

Comment: Do you know of any way to manually insert the ratings into the loop?

Comment: No, I don't, but check out the plugin, I'm pretty sure it can sort by rating, where rating is how may thumbs up.  It also looked like it had some trending feature, but I couldn't figure it out.